# Angular radio button patchValue with a json object

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

This is my first time building an Angular Reactive Form and it was all going well until I hit this problem.

I created the form in ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
...
'photoBundle': new FormControl,
...
this.addOns = this.formDataService.getAddOns();
this.addOnsForm.patchValue(this.addOns);
}
```

And I am trying to patch the values in for the form so that the user can navigate away, then return and the same values will be filled out/selected.

Everything is working perfectly except for one radio button group that is passing it's value as a json object.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let photo of photoOptions">
<div class="col-12">
<input type="radio" name="photoBundle" formControlName="photoBundle" [value]="photo" /> {{ photo.option }}{{ photo.price | currency }}
...
```

Where photoOptions is declared in the component

```
photoOptions = [ { option: '10 photos for ', price: 90 }, ... ];
```

And photo bundle is set in a model

```
export class AddOns {
...
photoBundle?: any = { option: '', price: null }
...
}
```

Every other formControl works in that the user can select a value navigate away, then return to that page and the value is still selected. However all the others are declared in the model as either string, boolean or number.

When I console.log my save and get functions everything is working properly i.e. the value of the photoBundle is something like { option: "10 photos for ", price: 90 }

I just can't seem to patch the value back into the Form so that the appropriate radio button is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated